# Gridview not scrolling horizontally in windows phone 8.1

Tags: winrt-xaml, windows-phone-8.1

.Gridview not scrolling horizontally in windows phone  app instead it is scrolling vertically.I just copy paste the code of my windows 8.1 app to windows phone 8.1 but it is scrolling vertically.

here is the xaml code:

```
    <Grid>
    <Grid.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="Assets/back3.png"></ImageBrush>
    </Grid.Background>

    <Grid.ChildrenTransitions>
        <TransitionCollection>
            <EntranceThemeTransition/>
        </TransitionCollection>
    </Grid.ChildrenTransitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="5*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height=".6*"/>

    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="70"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>

    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Text="Select Comic" Foreground="Black" FontSize="30" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"></TextBlock>
    <!-- Back button and page title -->
    <GridView x:Name="myGridview"  Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" SelectionChanged="myGridview_SelectionChanged">
        <GridView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel  Margin="0,0,20,20">
                    <Image Source="{Binding source}"  Width="100" Height="100" Stretch="Fill"></Image>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemTemplate>
    </GridView>


</Grid>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try by putting 
`ItemsPanel`,`ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Enabled" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"`

```
<GridView Width="400"  ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Enabled" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
    <GridView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"></VirtualizingStackPanel>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemsPanel>
    <GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel  Margin="0,0,20,20">
                <Image Source="{Binding source}"  Width="100" Height="100" Stretch="Fill"></Image>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemTemplate>
</GridView>
```

**Update**

try by changing  Itemspanel : WrapGrid Orientation="Vertical" or Orientation="Horizontal"

```
<GridView Width="400"  ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Enabled" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
    <GridView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapGrid Orientation="Vertical"></WrapGrid>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemsPanel>
    <GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel  Margin="0,0,20,20">
                <Image Source="{Binding source}"  Width="100" Height="100" Stretch="Fill"></Image>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemTemplate>
</GridView>
```

Comment: Its is scrolling horizontally but in one line?

Comment: If your GridView not scroll horizontally (returns to the start position on release your finger) just try to remove GridView's Width attribute