# how to make a listview horizontal in the Windows Phone 8.1 RT?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I am trying create a listview horizontal but my code is not working. someone know what I'm doing wrong?

I used this code to do the listview horizontal, but not work.

```
 <Canvas Height="100" VerticalAlignment="Top" x:Name="UxCanLayoutList" Background="#DDD">
        <ListView x:Name="UxLstFotos"
                 ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Enabled"

                 ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Disabled"
                   ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
                 ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"

                 Width="400"
                 Height="100"
                  >
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="100"></ColumnDefinition>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Height="100">
                            <Image  Source="{Binding Foto}" Height="70" Width="70"></Image>
                            <TextBlock Text="foto tirada" FontSize="10" Foreground="#000"></TextBlock>
                        </StackPanel>

                        </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>


        </ListView>

    </Canvas>
```

Comment: I think you need a different control. I don't think listview supports horizontal display of items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this gridview

```
   <GridView x:Name="grdSelectShape" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Enabled" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalRailEnabled="True" SelectionChanged="grdSelectShape_SelectionChanged"  >

                                <GridView.ItemsPanel>
                                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                        <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                </GridView.ItemsPanel>


                                <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>

                                            <Image Margin="5" Stretch="None"   Source="{Binding}" />

                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </GridView.ItemTemplate>

                            </GridView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try a GridView instead. Look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24677428/gridview-not-scrolling-horizontally-in-windows-phone-8-1) for guidance.

I believe gridview allows much finer grained control of display than does listview.

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with this also!
I created a project on my github and blogged about it in the past: http://depblog.weblogs.us/2015/03/25/show-items-scrolling-horizontally-with-listview-in-winrt/
https://github.com/Depechie/HorizontalScrollListView

In short: you need to change the ItemsPanelTemplate of the listview and adjust the ScrollViewer...